# attrs.$set('ngClick', functionName + '()'); no longer working in angular 1.2rc3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an open source project that I'm working on upgrading to work with angular 1.2rc3.  Essentially it handles promises on form buttons.  In this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/vQd97YEpYO20YHSuHnN0?p=preview you should be able to click "Save" on the right side and see a "clicked" appear in the console, because it should execute this code in the directive:

```
            scope[functionName] = function () {
                console.log('clicked');
                //if it's already busy, don't accept a new click
                if (scope.busy === true) {
                    return;
                }

                scope.busy = true;
                var ret = scope.$eval(onClick);
                if (angular.isDefined(ret) && ret.hasOwnProperty('then')) {
                    ret.then(function () {
                        scope.busy = false;
                    });
                }
            };
```

With 1.2, this method no longer gets executed despite the following code being executed:

```
            if (angular.isDefined(attrs.ngClick)) {
                console.log('test');
                attrs.$set('ngClick', functionName + '()');
            }
```

I haven't been able to figure out why this function won't get executed.... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the directive priorities [have changed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (see "Breaking Changes") in Angular 1.2.   Here's an [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0FELNkkOEmHG5SBchLK6?p=preview) which simply sets a negative priority on your busy button directive in `angular-form-ui.js`.

```
restrict: 'A',
priority: -100, // <-- This is the only change I made
controller: ...
```

This causes your directive, which replaces the value of the `ngClick` attribute, to execute before the `ngClick` directive uses the value of the attribute to [create a function pointer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L45-L49) using [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse).

Comment: This is absolutely a hack. If you want to change the value of ngClick before it gets bound you should be using the compile function instead of the link function.

Comment: @dtabuenc I hear you...   My answer explains why @Webnet 's directive broke which is what was asked.  Use of `priority` is part of the public API.  I guess whether it's use in this context is a "hack" is somewhat subjective but I do agree with you that I'd probably opt for packaging this busy functionality up as a directive distinct from `ngClick`.

Comment: It's not the use of priority that's a hack, it's the modifying the ng-click attribute in the link function that is a hack (it should be done in the compile). Using priority to make this work in it's current state is a hack in as far as it's just simply sweeping the problem under the rug for now). It is quite possible to break again in the future, since he is violating the contract for directives, which is that manipulation of the directives in the DOM should be done in the compile function, rather than the link function.

Answer (score 3):

You really should not be modifying the ng-click attribute from your link function. I think it's a fluke that it ever worked for you, and modifying the priority is  a hack. I think there is an easier way to do what you are trying to do though. Take a look at the modified plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EypQbCc5wpw5xBWSiVuA?p=preview

I modified your directive to be busy-click and replaces ng-click altogether. There's no point in using and manipulating ng-click (it is an extremely simple directive to begin with). Let me know if you have any questions.

BTW, if you did need to add or modify directives, you would do this through a compile function, never through the link function.

```
    directive('busyClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
          busyClick: '&',
          busyText: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            el.on('click', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){

                  console.log('clicked');
                  //if it's already busy, don't accept a new click
                  if (scope.busy === true) {
                    return;
                  }
                  setBusy();
                  var ret = scope.busyClick();
                  if (angular.isDefined(ret) && ret.hasOwnProperty('then')) {
                    ret.then(function () {
                        setNotBusy();
                    });
                  }

                });

            });

            var originalText = el.text();

            function setBusy(){
              scope.busy = true;
              el.addClass('busy')
              if(angular.isDefined(scope.busyText)){
                el.text(scope.busyText);
              }
            }

            function setNotBusy(){
              scope.busy = false;
              el.removeClass('busy')
              el.text(originalText);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I would definitely go this route if there wasn't as much of a usability gain from using `ng-click`

Comment: What do you mean by usability gain?

Comment: Developers are already familiar and used to use `ng-click`.  So implementation of this directive is much easier and intuitive if I utilize that as well.

Comment: just switch busyClick: '&' to busyClick: '&ngClick'  Check out this new plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EypQbCc5wpw5xBWSiVuA?p=preview