# Change ng-click function attribute. In Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function defined in a directive called old(), currently the button executes this function when clicking. I want when the directive is loaded, the old() function was changed to the new() function. The new function, would receive by parameter (this.form) ("form" is the name of my form). 
I've tried this, but it

```
attrs.$set('ngClick', 'new(this.form)');
```

but the new() function is not executed. How can I do it?.
I need to do this inside a directive, maybe it can be achieved in a controller, but I need to do it in a directive, and I put this example doubt to apply it in my real project. Thank you very much.

http://jsfiddle.net/mg8g138x/

```
    app.directive('validation', function ($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }

              scope.old= function(){
                alert("old")
              } 
             //attrs.$set('ngClick', 'new(this.form)');
              scope.new= function(form){
                alert("new");
                console.log(form)
              }                  

           }

        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to do it. Implement a function that will use both the use cases of the two functions you need to implement. Say for example if you want some x function during start then trigger functionx and then when an action has happened then trigger functiony which are called within the function old().

I definitely do not recommend change of attributes. But if you really wish t do it this is how you may want to for it..

```
app.directive('validation', function ($timeout) {

            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                require: 'ngModel', 

                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  if (!ngModel){
                    return;          
                  }

                  scope.previous= function(){
                    alert("old")
                  }

                 scope.old= scope.previous 

                  scope.new= function(form){
                    alert("new");
                    console.log(form)
                  }
                 // Do this action may be within a function after an action 
                 // or an event $emit/$broadcast rather than directly in code.
                 attrs.$set('ngClick', scope.old = scope.new); 
               }

            };
        });
```

Please have a look at this stackoverflow as well.
[attrs.$set('ngClick', functionName + '()'); no longer working in angular 1.2rc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572954/attrs-setngclick-functionname-no-longer-working-in-angular-1-2rc3)

Comment: Thank you!. But how can I get this.form, in the template (new (this.form))

Comment: I do this,  attrs.$set('ngClick', scope.old = scope.new(this.form));   but why does it run when I start the application? I need this to happen when I click on the button

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. But I'll explain a bit more. In the template a user should put in ng-click: ng-click = 'old (this.form); form.$valid && new() '. I do not want you to put this long line. That is why from the directive I want to add this line so that in the end the user only has to put ng-click = 'new()'. The directive will construct ng-click="old (this.form); form. $valid && new()"

Comment: change the implementation to `ng-click="old(form)"` for the previous function it will be undefined and for the new function the value will be fetched.

Comment: You dont have to do anything just pass the form item. Its will be undefined for the first and captured for second

Answer (score 0):

the reason while your new function doesn't work is because by the time the code in your link function run, AngularJS had already finished compiled the template, and link all found directives (ng-click) with the directive scope.

Once you change your ng-click value to a new function, you will need to re-compile the directive in order to make that change effective.

You can have a look at angularjs $compile service to see how it can be used: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile.

However, I don't believe it's the best approach to your problem, as Javascript has some functional programming feature, which allow you to pass a function as a parameter, you can merge the **old function** and **new function** into a single function, and control which function to be called via a parameters, here is the example:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (!ngModel){
      return;          
   }

   scope.old = function(){
       alert("old");
   }

   scope.new = function(form){
       alert("new");
      console.log(form)
   }

   scope.current = scope.old; // variable to control with function being called
   scope.form = ''; // variable to contain the parameter for the function called via ng-click

   scope.binding_to_button = function(function_to_call, parameter) {
       function_to_call(parameter);
   }
                 // Do this action may be within a function after an action 
                 // or an event $emit/$broadcast rather than directly in code.
   scope.current = scope.new;
   scope.form = form; // 
               }
```

And then, instead of binding **scope.new** or **scope.old** directly to your ng-click, binding **scope.binding_to_button**.

```
ng-click="binding_to_button(current, form)"
```

This function will take the **$scope.current** as it first parameter, and the **$scope.form** as its second, so you can dynamically control which function to be called and what parameters passed to them via the click event.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. But I'll explain a bit more. In the template a user should put in ng-click: ng-click = 'old (this.form); form.$valid && new() '. I do not want you to put this long line. That is why from the directive I want to add this line so that in the end the user only has to put ng-click = 'new()'. The directive will construct  ng-click="old (this.form); form. $valid && new()"

Comment: Hi yavg, if it's the case you don't even need the closure, why don't you check the condition inside the click handler and call the new or old function accordingly ?